# How to access resource from Windows Runtime Component?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

With a C# class library, I could build my `.xslt`resource an embedded resource, and access like so:

```
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("myfile.xslt");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
```

With a Windows runtime component, I don't seem to be able to do that (assembly.Getexecutingassembly doesn't exist), so I guess it's not allowed in the runtime. I can use `Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` and select content for the resource type, but only if I put the file in the project I am referencing the component from, which I don't want to do every time (unless I'm doing it wrong). What can I do to access the resource from the component?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. Set the resource to "content", then:

```
var document = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///NAMESPACENAME/file.xslt"));
```